# Viewing SQL SP resultsets instead of output parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL server SP with output parameters and a couple of select statements in the SP body. I want to run the SP from Management studio and want to see the output of the Select queries within the SP body(& not the output parameters)

```
declare @name1 nvarchar(10)
exec sp1 1,@name1 out
print @name1
```

If I use the able set of commands it just returns me the output parameter but I want to see the output of the select queries within the SP. How do I do that from Management studio

Comment: A straight select within an SP, run from SSMS will show in the results pane the same as a regular select. Are you sure you are doing a regular select within your SP?

Comment: its not showing the results of the select query....just the output of the print statement.

Comment: That a different output window though? Thats the "Messages" window, check your "Results" window. If there is nothing there then please post your code.